# Accurate DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 time fields in SQL. I want to calculate the difference between start time and end time in hours.

From 7 AM in the morning to 7:30 PM it would be 12.5 hours but the datediff function returns 12 hours because it returns an integer.

I also tried converting it to seconds:

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(HOUR,'07:00:00.0000000', '19:30:00.0000000')); 

SELECT (DATEDIFF(SECOND,'07:00:00.0000000', '19:30:00.0000000'))/3600;

SELECT (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,'07:00:00.0000000', '19:30:00.0000000'))/3600000;
```

All of these return 12 hours which is not accurate. Is there a way to do a difference between 2 time values in SQL accurately?

Comment: Aside: Note that [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says: "This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate." If the part is `hour` then `07:00` to `08:00`, `07:59` to `08:00` and `07:00` to `08:59` are _all_ a difference of `1` hour crossing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force a `decimal` result instead of an `int` result - which you can do by changing 3600 to 3600.00.

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(SECOND,'07:00:00.0000000', '19:30:00.0000000'))/3600.00;
```

Knowing the datatype, precision and scale of the result of a mathematical operation is unfortunately not straight forward in SQL Server. I recommend taking a read of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale) and its associated links for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does integer division.  So, you need to divide by a number with a decimal point:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'07:00:00.0000000', '19:30:00.0000000') / 3600.0;
```

You could also cast the `DATEDIFF()` to a numeric or floating point value for this purpose.